# manipulate running VLC with java

Tags: java, controls, vlc

First of all, I have to precise that I am a 2d year bachelor student, so I'm still learning computer science and I'm not an expert. I have to implement a java program that can control VLC (tells it to play, stop etc.) while VLC is already running. My problem is that I can't figure out what APIs or java classes I should use in order to access VLC from my application. Since I didn't know where to start, I made quite a lot of researching and I bumped in some possibly interesting things:

- firstly I thought Java Media Framework could help, but it seems that its purpose is to create kind of a fake graphical player with which you can stream multimedia files inside the java app, but that's not what I need
- then I found out such VLCJ that *seems* to be what I need, but I still didn't get how it is exactly and how it works

So now my question is: is this VLCJ the right way? And in this case can someone please explain me how to use it or at least suggesting a point where to start? Should I use Runtime and Process classes to connect to VLC?

Otherwise, if I'm on the wrong way, are there any other solutions suitable for my problem?

PS: I also read something about a Remote Control Interface, but the explanations I've found are about some graphical content and not so clear, so I haven't gone deeper with that.

Comment: Doesn't VLC have a "service" you can communicate with? For example https://www.videolan.org/doc/vlc-user-guide/en/ch05.html

Comment: If you want to control an already running instance of vlc, then vlcj is not for you and you should do like MadProgrammer says. If you want to embed an instance of vlc inside your own Java application, then vlcj can be used for that.